# Are obvious questions, or questions that are extremely easy, but have no concrete evidence on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently came across and answered [Who are the Trainers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259124/who-are-the-trainers/259153). It currently has a -3 vote as of this posting, and [GarrettJ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/71074/garrettj) has posted a comment:

> Probably because the answer is obvious. Like all games, you can practice against the AI. Supercell doesn't pay thousands of people to sit down in their offices and hope people want to train against them. Supercell gave them random names and gives them a random deck from cards that are near your level

Although it's really improbable that Supercell would hire real human trainers, is this question on-topic? I see that the downvote when moused over says

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

As this question does not appear show any research, I have since downvoted the question. However, in doing some searching, I haven't found any concrete confirmation that the trainers are AI. All I have is my own personal experience that could be incorrect, but I am 99.99% sure is correct. Is the question on-topic?

Also, while [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/whats-the-policy-regarding-easy-questions) meta post may be related, it assumes that there is hard evidence, like the game's own website or a Wikipedia page. In this case, as the game is very new, there are no sources(at least, none that I could find) that confirm that the trainers are AI or human.

Answer (score 5):

They are on topic, as they are related to gaming as defined by our scope (e.g. not something that requires outside knowledge such as a developer interview). However, just because a question is on topic doesn't make it a good question. People are allowed to downvote anything they want, as there is a **subjective** element to the quality of a question. I don't know anything about the game or question mentioned so I can't comment specifically, but people downvoting is how the system is supposed to work. If people are using close votes on a question only because they don't like it and not because there is a fundamental problem with the question, then we have an issue (albeit an entirely different one).

Comment: The question is currently deleted. Is there any reason this might be, or is it totally unrelated to this topic?

Comment: @Ghalid The user could have self-deleted (as people sometimes do to get the reputation from negative-scoring questions back) as long as no answers were posted. Somebody with 10k rep or a moderator would have to look at the deleted question to see for sure, but that would be my guess.

Comment: @JoshPetrie - I had a look for you, it was deleted by Ashley Nunn, a mod. You might consider pinging her in chat if you want her to weigh in on this meta :)